# jQuery DIV Flip

Tags: jquery, flip, flippy

This is the HTML

```
<article class="post">
    <div class="post-inner">
        <div class="post-content">
            // stuff here   
            <button class="order">Order</button>
        </div>
        <div class="post-content-back">
            // stuff here
            <button class="back">Back</button>
        </div><!-- / .post-back -->
    </div>
</article>
```

I'm using this [flippy plugin](http://blog.guilhemmarty.com/flippy/) to flip front and back views, but it just doesn't work for some reason that I can't figure:

```
jQuery(".post .order").bind("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).parents(".post-content").flippy({
        content:jQuery(this).next().find(".post-content-back"),
        direction:"LEFT",
        duration:"750",
        onStart:function(){
            alert("Let's flip");
        },
        onFinish:function(){
            alert("ok, it's flipped :)");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: is there any errors in the console (press f12 in most browsers )

Comment: I got a JavaScript error `Uncaught ReferenceError: g is not defined` using this code - see my answer which explains why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to supply a `background-color` to the `.post-content` element.

The plugin does this on line #217

```
_Color = convertColor($this.css("background-color"));
```

and it is grabbing the `background-color` property, which if **not** supplied is defaulting to `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` (well it does for me on Chrome)

When flipping line #312 uses that color string like this:

```
ctx.fillStyle = (_Ang > 90) ? changeColor(_Color_target,Math.floor(Math.sin(rad)*_Light)) : changeColor(_Color,-Math.floor(Math.sin(rad)*_Light));
```

and calls the `changeColor(colorHex,step)` function at line #441, which is expecting a hex value for the color. Not supplying a hex string causes the script to explode when it tries to extract hex values for red, green, blue from `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` with the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: g is not defined`

The function tries to use `gb` as red,  `a(` as green and `0,` as blue.

Added a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zMvA5/) but it's quite a localised question so I don't think there is benefit to inlining all that code in this answer.

@tommarshall's answer is also very relevant as you do have a selector issue finding the `.post-content-back` element.

Comment: AAAAH! That was it, I would've never solved it myself and someone above gave me a negative rep for the question :S

Comment: -2 is not much to worry about :-) I think, if a user is deleted any rep anyone got from them goes as well! Also, you got a +1 from me so you're now +3 up

Answer (score 2):

The problem here was that way that you were fetching the content.

```
jQuery(this).next().find(".post-content-back"),
```

This will return the next element (which is .post-content-back) and then look for an element with the class .post-content-back inside it. And then you were returning the jQuery object itself rather than the content.

Here's what you actually wanted:

```
jQuery(this).next(".post-content-back").html();
```

However it's also better to fetch the content before initialising the flippy plugin and storing it in a variable.

Here's a working example - http://jsfiddle.net/SqD6x/

Comment: Thanks, but it still alerts "lets flip", hides .post-content and shows an empty maybe 10px height box.

Comment: It's alerting let's flip because that's whats defined in the onStart callback? If you don't want the alerts then remove the callbacks - http://jsfiddle.net/SqD6x/1/

Comment: Not sure what you mean by hides .post-content or the 10px height box.

Comment: ok, so onclick it should hide (flip) .post-content and show .post-content-back right? It hides the post-content div but thats it, doesn't flip and show the other div